# Android - Stop HTTP request

Tags: android, post

How can I stop the request to the server ? ...I want to disconnect from the server once the user press cancel button.
I used .diconnect() method but the application get force close

Comment: Short of killing the thread there isn't much you can do until the server responds, I believe.

Comment: Which HTTP client are you using? An subclass of `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase` supports an `abort` method

Comment: Which mean I can not stop the request

Comment: @ Cody Caughlan I used HttpURLConnection

Comment: Can you post your code, as well as the error messages you get from the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we've hit the same issue. There doesn't seem to be a "clean" way to cancel a connection, so we just wrap ours up in `try { ... } catch`.

If you're playing in this area, you're also likely to discover that `URLConnection` doesn't timeout correctly either. This is a good description of the problem:

http://thushw.blogspot.com/2010/10/java-urlconnection-provides-no-fail.html